# Could not find method android() for arguments org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i have just imported a project(working) to my android studio.
first when it imported, im getting this error:

> build tools is not working .api 23...

then i followed some answer in stackoverflow with my same error(question).

i go to `file>project structure>select module>`and choose :

compile sdk version = 6.0;
build tools version = 23.0.1.

then, i clean project...

and i got this error :

> Error:(16, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ThreatMap'.
>
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_760vbdomi0tz2p8mkdshyqph9$_run_closure2@5e6cdc1e] on root project 'ThreatMap' of type org.gradle.api.Project...

heres the code in build.gradle (project-level):

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { jcenter() } 
    
    dependencies { } 
} 

allprojects { 
    repositories { jcenter() } 
} 

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 23 
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' 
} 

dependencies { }
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.threatmapper"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     
            'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'
}
```

sdk android version installed

[image: sdk]

Comment: tried cleaning the project?

Comment: I think you are missing the project-level build.gradle file. Do you know where to create it and what should it have?

Comment: @Chisko .no its not missing. heres the code in build.gradle(project-level):  


'buildscript {  
    repositories {  
        jcenter()  
    }  
    dependencies {  
    }  
}  
allprojects {  
    repositories {  
        jcenter()  
    }  
}  
  
android {  
    compileSdkVersion 23  
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'  
}  
dependencies {  
}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not missing, but messed up. You are not adding the gradle wrapper to the project. It should contain something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' 
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

the 2.2.2 corresponds to the most recent version of Android Studio. Replace that with yours. And I also would suggest to move the 
`android { compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' }` 
block to the module's build.gradle file

Comment: thanks alot man. gradle wrapper added!. iknow now that there's the difference between the gradle (project and module level).

Comment: Glad I could help out. Consider returning the favour and upvote if my answer helped you solve your problem.